# Does electrical exposure build human resilience?

Tags: death, resistance, electricity

So I stumbled on [this website](http://bernel.blogspot.com/2013/06/top-10-fictional-characters-that-have.html) about shocking electrical superheroes and I was wondering if a shock was administered every day to a young person, would their heart slowly give out, or would they become virtually impervious to electrocution?

Comment: I deleted all the click bait from your post. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. You would either kill them with the first shock or just annoy them every day of their life. Human tissue can't adapt to electricity. It's either enough current to damage it or it's not. And if the path of the current is through the heart, [the amount needed](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~p616/safety/fatal_current.html) to disrupt the heart's electrical functioning is as little as 100 milliamps.

Comment: Source for the inadaptability of human tissue?

Comment: @Adamawesome4 You want me to find evidence that your hypothesis is false? That's not how it works. There are mountains of indisputable evidence that electricity harms animal tissue, and that's more than sufficient to support my position. It's your hypothesis that tissue can adapt to electricity and not be harmed by it, which runs counter to that mountain of evidence. So the burden is on you to find evidence supporting your rather novel hypothesis that defies all that's known about electricity and animal tissue.

Comment: I know that it takes just a bit to kill the subject, but I wanted to know, over time, can tissue become more suitable for taking slightly larger voltages? Is there no formal research on this yet? I have found sources for why the heart is weak when introduced to even minimal currents, but have found nothing on its adequacy to change to suit electricity.

Comment: @Adamawesome4 No, there is no formal research because it's not a practical question. I don't know why you think it's even possible. If human tissue was a circuit board, an engineer would do one of two things to protect against outside electrical interference: 1) they would add insulation, or 2) they would add grounded shielding to direct the interference away from the circuit. Animal tissue isn't capable of growing either thing, so how would you imagine it could adapt?